# need to assign values from sql query in single instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing the below query in sql-server-2008-R2 which gives me output as I wanted(i.e, number of rows) but, I want to store the result in form of a multi-columned row(s) in a variable.

```
declare @rCount int
declare @kuri nvarchar(max)
declare @IDs nvarchar(max)

select @rCount=10

set @kuri='select top '+cast(@rCount as varchar)+' FLD295,FLD9 from tableName (nolock) ORDER BY NEWID()'

execute(@kuri)
```

I had done this earlier but it was different query where I need to concatenate the result of both the queries in to one column (assigning and display)

```
select @IDs=CAST(isnull(@IDs ,'')as varchar)+CAST(COALESCE(fld9,',')as varchar) from table1307 (nolock) ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: select @IDs=CAST(isnull(@IDs ,'')as varchar)+CAST(COALESCE(fld9,',')as varchar),* from table1307 (nolock) ORDER BY NEWID() 
need alternative to write query like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
    FLD9 bigint
, FLD295 nVARCHAR(max)
)

insert into @T1(,FLD295,FLD9) 
select top(@rCount) FLD295,FLD9 from tableName (nolock)
 ORDER BY NEWID()

select * from @T1
select @IDs=CAST(isnull(@IDs ,'')as varchar)+CAST(COALESCE(fld9,',')as varchar) from @T1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the face that you can do

```
declare @i int=3

select top(@i) .... –
```

2008 does support dynamic top

I hope you know that result should be single. , otherwise , it can't be possible (unless you're doing `insert into...`

if you're asking about how to concatenate ( cte is jsut  table , ignore it)

[image]

Comment: it give me multiple rows
i used COALESCE function

Comment: @KashurLadk-e so how would you store multiple values in a single nvarchar ? it can be concatenated via `,` or you should store them in a table(!)

Comment: select @IDs=CAST(isnull(@IDs ,'')as varchar)+CAST(COALESCE(fld9,',')as varchar) from table1307 (nolock) ORDER BY NEWID()

Comment: c the above query in ur coment
i had written this query couple of times bcoz at first instance it displays result and at second instance it assigns the value

Comment: @KashurLadk-e what about it ?sorry I dont understand what you mean

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52649/discussion-between-kashur-ladk-e-and-royi-namir)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor for access result set:

```
declare @rCount int
declare @kuri nvarchar(max)
declare @IDs nvarchar(max)

declare @FLD295 int
declare @FLD9 int

select @rCount=10

set @kuri='declare cursor curs for select top '+cast(@rCount as varchar)+' FLD295,FLD9 from tableName (nolock) ORDER BY NEWID()'

exec sp_executesql @kuri

open curs
fetch from curs
into @FLD295, @FLD9

while @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIn


fetch from curs
into @FLD295, @FLD9
END

close curs
deallocate curs
```

Comment: Don't kill a fly with a shotgun